# Exists (-like) function for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check the existence of an element in jQuery?

Currently snip of my code looks like this:

```
if ($(selector).length>0) {
    // This should do something
}
```

Is there some kind of function, or a plugin that could work with this? Is there any better way to approach this?

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: if `$(selector).length` is 0, then it means that there are no elements that matches the provided `selector` value. So if you pick `$(.foo)` and its length is 0, then there are no elements with such class name.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz The code is not self documenting or self-explanatory. I completely understand why this question is being asked. The code just so happens to do what OP wants. If you wanted to know if your friend has a girlfriend, would you ask them "Is your girlfriend taller than 0cm?"

Comment: @TahaPaksu "Possible duplicate" more like "exact duplicate"

Comment: Yea I know, that's an auto comment in SO when you flag the post as duplicate ;)